# Adapting to Changes in Thai Medical School Entrance Exam Scoring System: Seeking Statistical Adjustment Solutions

Tags: statistical-significance, data-transformation

The Thai medical school entrance exam comprises three aptitude tests and other subject tests, each with their own weight. The table below shows how to calculate the total score.

[image]

Students rely on past statistics to secure a position at top-tier schools. The table shows the lowest total score accepted and the mean total score in 2023 for the top three institutions.

[image]

Recently, the test writers admitted to [plagiarizing](https://bnnbreaking.com/world/thailand/thai-tpat1-exam-controversy-triggers-nationwide-outcry/) the IQ assessment test, which led to its cancellation and a change in the scoring system. The max total score is now calculated as 90, with the aptitude tests weight reduced to 20.

[image]

This change has made it difficult for students to rely on past statistics when applying to med schools. Scaling past total scores into a 90 base is not an appropriate solution since it overlooks the cancelled IQ assessment test's impact on the total score.

**I’ve been wondering what the best way is to statistically adjust the past scores to match the current situation.**

**The past statistics we have include the maximum, minimum, and mean scores for each test, as well as the maximum, minimum, and mean scores of students accepted by each institution, as shown in the second table.**

Comment: Can't you just compute the new total score as a fraction of 90% rather than 100%? I find it odd that you'd want to recast all the old scores as a new score representation a portion of 90% - it's very strange to me that 90% would represent a perfect score with full marks on everything, it seems like a rather misleading use of percentages to pick the denominator to be higher than what it actually 100%.

Comment: Your use of the term % "percent" is ill advised, here, at least in the post-plagiarism setting. Recommend you edit the question to refer to "points" instead, which total to max of 100 or max of 90 points.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.